# Camel netty4-http sets invalid host http header in request

Tags: apache-camel

The netty4-http component is setting an invalid "host" HTTP header when no port is defined in the uri for requests.

netty4-http sets the header in  DefaultNettyHttpBinding.toNettyRequest where URI is used to parse the uri string but URI give -1 if no port is defined.
For example the host header could be set to "hostname:-1" which is not accepted of some proxy servers that check the validity of the host header.
For example Apache proxy will return a http error 400(Bad request).

<strike>Also see ch. "14.23 Host" https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html for definition.</strike>

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4

```java
// This is how it's done in DefaultNettyHttpBinding.toNettyRequest
URI u = new URI(uri);
String hostHeader = u.getHost() + (u.getPort() == 80 ? "" : ":" + u.getPort());
request.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.HOST.toString(), hostHeader);
LOG.trace("Host: {}", hostHeader);
```

As a workaround I'm using a custom NettyHttpBinding class but it had been nice to get a fix for it.

Comment: First, don't reference RFC 2616 any further as by Mark Nottingham, one of the heads behind the HTTP spec, [RFC 2616 is dead](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead). Use RFC 7230-7235 instead. Next, I'm not sure how we should help on this issue other than link you to [Camel's JIIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CAMEL/issues/CAMEL-13851?filter=allopenissues) itself where you should file a new issue, if it does not yet exist.

Comment: It seems that you have identified a bug and also the required fix. As camel is open-source, you may consider [to contribute](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) to it.

Comment: Thanks, I will create an issue and if time allows dig in to how to contribute.

Comment: @Urken Did you ever report this bug? If so do you have a link to the task?